# Upload Images as array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, image-uploading

I am trying to upload multiple images to a folder and is working properly. I have  a problem when i am trying to store the name of images in database. If i upload just one is working. If i upload more than one I get just one name in my database.

Whats the way to upload, making an array with images titles, to my db?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="maindiv">
<div id="formdiv">
    <h4>Upload Image for </h4>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
        <p class="alert alert-info">Only JPEG,PNG,JPG Type Image Uploaded. Image Size Should Be Less Than 100KB.</p>
        <hr/>
        <div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div><br/>
        <input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="add_images" id="upload" class="upload"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is my php:

```
if (isset($_POST['add_images'])) {
$j = 0; 
$target_path = "images/";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
    $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");  
    $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//store extensions in the variable
    $name_of_img = basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
    $target_path = $target_path . $name_of_img;
    $j = $j + 1;
      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 1000000) 
            && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
            echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            print_r($name_of_img);
            $query = "UPDATE post SET ";   
            $query .= "images = '{$name_of_imgs}' ";
            $query .= "WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id}";    
            $update_cruise_img = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);  
        } else {
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
        echo $j. ').<span id="error">Wrong file Size or Type</span><br/><br/>';
    }
}
 }
```

I tried by creating array like this `$name_of_imgs = json_encode($_POST['file']);`
 but is not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `post` table outside the `for` loop.

```
if (isset($_POST['add_images'])) {
  $j = 0; 
  $name_of_imgs = [];

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
      $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");  
      $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//store extensions in the variable
      $name_of_img = basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);

      // define target path here so that it won't concat the last value 
      $target_path = "images/" . $name_of_img;

      $j = $j + 1;
      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 1000000) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
             echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';

             $name_of_imgs[] = $name_of_img;
          } else {
              echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
          }
      } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
          echo $j. ').<span id="error">Wrong file Size or Type</span><br/><br/>';
      }
  }

  // update here
  $query = "UPDATE post SET ";   
  $query .= "images = '" . implode(',', $name_of_imgs) . "' ";
  $query .= "WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id}";    
  $update_cruise_img = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);  

}
```

You may consider creating another table for images.

Comment: No is still doing the same.. With this code just changed the name of image in my folder, In database it keeps store just the name of last image

Comment: Can you put `print_r($name_of_imgs);` after the loop? So you could see if all images are in `$name_of_imgs` variable

Comment: Yes i did.. I print_r and my query as well and is like that                      UPDATEpost SET images = '' WHEREpost_id = 17Array ( )

Comment: Can you try that. I removed the initial value of `$target_path` outside the loop.

Comment: No still the same

Comment: So that means `$name_of_img` has no value. Or maybe this condition `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path))` is always false.

Comment: Thats the wierd $name has value because images are uploaded to folder with their names, also stored in database but just the name of last image not as array that I want to so i can display the images in post

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have run update query in upload file. it's make sure this_post_id in single that's way may be update record in single file name.

Comment: The id is ok. I can upload the image to the folder and store it in database. But if I upload multiple images they created in folder but store just one image in db and I want to store all in db as array